# how to select rows from mysql database according to multiple specification

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have an array, $username which contains a a bunch of username, like(lets make it simple to list 4 values)

```
$username[0]='nicholas', $username[1]='Jane', $username[2]='Frank',$username[3]='Ben'
```

I have a table in database like

```
id username   post    timestamp
1  nicholas   hello    13932... 
2  Jane       world    13922... 
3  kesong     yes      13978...
4  Frank      bad      13374...
5  Sim        tii      13842...
6  Ben        tisue    13149...
```

I want to select the rows which only match my values on the array,$username, and order by timestamp

Instead of:

```
//list all the value
$query="SELECT FORM `table1` WHERE `username`='nicholas' || `username`='Jane' ORDER BY timestamp "
```

any convenient way to fulfill this job because the array always change its value

Comment: have you tried using the IN clause ? You can construct a string from your array which you can then pass to the query using the IN clause. It may not be secure against SQL injection though. You might need to take additional precautions for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best method is to construct you query with an `IN` clause.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

If all your searchable names are contained in `$username`, you could create a dynamic query, like so:

```
"SELECT FORM table1 WHERE username IN ('".implode("','", $username)."') ORDER BY timestamp"
```

Comment: implode is a php function.  I'm using it to help construct the query string.  You could also iterate over the array in a foreach, or something.  But this method is better, in my opinion.

Comment: yes, may be I can create a varible that is $string=implode(',',$username), and use it later IN($string), can this work, because I don't want to get confused about the quotation

Comment: that's a problem, when we send the $string, which is like "nicolas,kesong,Jane", and pass it like IN($string), it's not working because it would consider to be a whole string and begin to search the  username "nicolas,kesong,Jane",which is not exist, instead of search them seperately

Comment: Notice, that instead of `implode(',',$username)` I used `"'".implode("','", $username)."'"`.  My method will create the string as "'nicolas','kesong','Jane'" etc.